# Is there a way to make a button add a value to a JS variable in JavaScript/HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm learning to code in JavaScript and HTML to try and learn some web development and I am trying to figure out how to make a HTML button be able to add a value to a JavaScript variable

My code is not working how I would like. You can probably tell what I'm trying to do but can someone tell me how I'm meant to do it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var number = 123;

    function docWrite(variable) {
      document.write(variable);
    }

    function addOne(variable) {
      variable + 1
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>
    <script>
      docWrite(number)
    </script>
  </h1>
  <button><script>addOne(number)</script></button>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I think you need `<button onclick="addOne(number)"></button>`.

Comment: Why are you putting scripts inside elements like that?

Comment: Are you under the impression that putting the `docWrite(number)` call inside the `<h1>` will result in the `document.write(variable)` writing to that element? Because that's not quite how that works: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write

Comment: "*You can probably tell what I'm trying to do*" - while we can - *probably* - correctly guess your intent, it's your responsibility to explain (precisely) what you want to do. Reading broken code - or code that doesn't work as required - to infer your intent is not reliable. Please, read the guidance on "*[ask]*," and then [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0):

First, the problems:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // you create a global variable (which allows the value to be changed anywhere
    // in your code, which can easily cause problems; especially if you're using a
    // common variable name, for example the variable i inside of a loop):
    var number = 123;

    // this is ok, but there's no sanity checks so the function will (attempt) to
    // work with whatever argument is passed, whether it's a number, string,
    // Array, Object, Boolean...
    function docWrite(variable) {
      // document.write() has many problems, too many to list here, so please
      // read the link below (in the "references" section), basically: don't
      // use it, instead target a specific element, or node, and update that
      // via its properties or attributes:
      document.write(variable);
    }

    // again, basically okay but also no sanity checks, and you're not returning
    // a result to a calling context, so nothing can happen if, or when, the
    // function is called:
    function addOne(variable) {
      variable + 1
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>
    <script>
      <!-- you're calling the function with an undeclared, undefined variable,
           which will result in an error: -->
      docWrite(number)
    </script>
  </h1>
  
  <!-- there's no text in the button, so the user has no clue as to what action
       will occur (hint: never press an unidentified <button>) and, again, you're
       calling the function with an undeclared, undefined variable, which will
       lead to an error: -->
  <button><script>addOne(number)</script></button>


</body>

</html>
```

To try to offer a working approach – and bear in mind that I'm having to infer your intent, from reading the broken code in your question – I'd suggest the following; this code has explanatory notes within:

```js
// defining a function, named "adjust," using Arrow function syntax; this function
// takes one argument, a reference to the event that triggered the function; this
// is passed automatically from the EventTarget.addEventListener() method used
// later in this example:
const adjust = (evt) => {

  // here we use document.querySelector() to retrieve the first element in
  // the document that matches the supplied CSS selector; if there are no
  // matching elements this will return null:
  let counter = document.querySelector('.counter'),
    // evt.currentTarget returns the element to which this function
    // was bound, evt.currentTarget.dataset.action returns the
    // value of the data-* attribute with the name of "action." Note that
    // we're also using the optional chaining operator ('?.'), this
    // means that if we have the 'evt.currentTarget' (<button>), but
    // that element has no 'dataset' property this returns undefined
    // instead of throwing an error (unfortunately the prettier
    // functionality, to tidy code, here on SO and over on JS Fiddle
    // fails to recognise this, so clicking 'tidy' will introduce a
    // syntax error that needs to be corrected every single time):
    action = evt.currentTarget?.dataset?.action;

  // if there is no counter element-node (using the NOT operator),
  // or there is no "action" value:
  if (!counter || !action) {
    // we return false; this could be adjusted to whatever you
    // would prefer to return/receive in the event of failure:
    return false;
  }

  // here we retrieve the textContent of the counter element,
  // use String.prototype.trim() to remove any leading/trailing
  // white-space, and then use parseInt() to convert that String
  // into a base-10 number (hence the second argument of 10):
  let currentValue = parseInt(counter.textContent.trim(), 10),
    // here we check if the data-action attribute-value (that
    // we retrieved earlier) is equal to the string of 'increment,'
    // we're using a ternary/conditional operator here, so
    // if action is exactly equal to 'increment' we assign
    // +1 to the step variable, otherwise we return -1:
    step = "increment" === action ? +1 : -1;

  // if we have a current value:
  if (currentValue) {
    // we set the textContent of the counter element to be equal
    // to the result of currentValue + the step variable:
    counter.textContent = currentValue + step;
  } else {
    // otherwise, we assume no current value, and set the
    // text of the element to be equal to step:
    counter.textContent = step;
  }
};

// here we use document.querySelectorAll() to retrieve all
// elements matching the supplied selector; and then we
// use NodeList.prototype.forEach() to iterate over all
// the elements that were found:
document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(
  // using an Arrow function as the callback, 'btn' is a
  // reference to the current Node of the NodeList (the
  // name is arbitrary, but the reference will always
  // be the first argument); within the function we
  // use EventTarget.addEventListener() to bind the
  // adjust() function (note the deliberate lack of
  // parentheses) as the event-handler for the 'click'
  // event on the current <button>:
  (btn) => btn.addEventListener('click', adjust)
);
```

```css
/* using CSS to show the initial value for the
   element when it has no content: */

.counter:empty::before {
  content: '0';
}
```

```html
<!-- I have no idea why you chose to use a <h1> element, but I'm following that
     lead, here we've also used an element with the class of 'counter' to contain
     the value you wished to increment (though I'm adding decrement functionality
     as part of this example): -->
<h1>Lorem ipsum, with a counter: <span class="counter"></span></h1>
<!-- defining two buttons, with visible text for the user to see in order that
     they have some idea what to expect from interacting; I'm also using
     custom data-* attributes to allow the function to determine the "purpose": -->
<button type="button" data-action="increment">Increment</button>
<button type="button" data-action="decrement">Decrement</button>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jvq9ky6s/).

References:

- [Conditional ("ternary") operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_operator).
- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
- [`document.write()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write).
- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
- [`HTMLElement.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset).
- [`if...else` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else).
- [`NodeList.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach).
- [NOT `!` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_NOT).
- [Optional chaining operator `?.`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).
- [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).
- [Strict equality operator `===`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality)
- [`String.prototype.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim).

Answer (score -1):

First thing, your button is empty, with no text the button can't appear.
So you need to add text to your button like this:

```
<button>Add one</button>
```

Second thing you need to call your addOne function each time your button is pressed with a onclick trigger :

```
<button onclick="addOne(number)"></button>
```

After these two things you need to edit some things in your JS

```
let number = 123;

function docWrite(variable) {
  var h1 = document.querySelector('h1');
  h1.innerHTML = 'Current value:' + variable
}

function addOne(variable) {
  variable++
  number = variable
  docWrite(variable)
}
docWrite(number)
```

First select and edit your h1 tag with innerHTML otherwise you will overwrite your full document on first click. With document.selector & innerHTML only your tag will be edit.

In addOne Function i've replaced variable +1 with variable++(The same but cleaner), rewrite number so your value is updated for your next itteration  then write again on your h1

With these things your code should work. :)

I've grouped JS also ( cleaner )
Hope it will help
Full code : https://codepen.io/ColinMsd/pen/WNLJdmp?editors=1001

Post Edit: For your button you can also use AddEventListener to call an event on each click like this:

```
var button = document.querySelector('button')
button.addEventListener('click', addOne(number))
```

And HTML:

```
<button>Add one</button>
```

Same result just a bit more complicated process but much cleaner:)

Comment: addEventListener should be used instead of disseminating inline on* attribute handlers in HTML

Comment: Yes i would use it but for a beginer like him i was not sure he has already seen this option. As he put a onclick function in his code i followed the way he did trying to not get him lost

Comment: We're not w3schools to teach beginners the worst possible coding patterns. Let's try to teach beginners the *better*, proper way to do stuff.

Comment: Edited it with a addEventListener part. In my way you gotta walk before run and if he didn't learn it before he would just get lost

Comment: Exactly. Therefore to walk properly we should teach addEventListener. `on*` handlers should be in the *"run"* handbook's section.